# Why are my headphones not working?

Tags: 16.04, sound, alsa, headphones

My problem is that my headphones don't output any sound in Ubuntu 16.04. I'm aware that this topic has been discussed here many times, but I've tried some solutions but they didn't work. When I plug in my headphones and run `alsamixer`, it shows:

[image]

My headphone volume is on 100 so I don't understand why no sound is coming out of them. I'm new to Ubuntu and Linux in general. What should I do?

Answer (score -1):

Try use `pulse audio` to check if the headphones are automatically selected as output, and if they are not, you can manually change it. Its really easy to use and simple to understand.

Program here:

[Pulse Audio](https://freedesktop.org/software/pulseaudio/pavucontrol/#download)

Comment: I checked it and they are selected as output and that progress bar jumps when i play music but I hear nothing.

Comment: I know thats going to sound silly but, you made sure the headphones work on some other device, right?

Comment: I figure out , when i shut down PC and start Ubuntu headphones working, but when I firstly start Windows and than Ubuntu headphones doesn't working. It is weird.

Comment: What do you mean with "start windows"? Do you have the program "pavucontrol"?